# Can I run code at Alfresco startup?

Tags: alfresco

I have an Alfresco module that I would like to have do some cleanup when a new version of it is installed.

In the current situation, an older version of the module created a folder node with custom properties at the root of the repository. We've since decided to have multiple such nodes, and none of them at that location. I'd like to put into the next version of the module code that would run at Alfresco startup, check for the existence of the old node, copy its properties into the appropriate new nodes, and delete the old node.

Is such a thing possible? I've looked at the Bootstrap configuration file, but that appears to only allow one to add things to the repository, not modify or delete them.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you write a patch. That is a class that implements 
`org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.AbstractPatch`

Then you can do pretty much anything you want on bootstrap (except executing searches against solr since it wont be available).

Add some spring configuration, take a look at the file patch-services-context.xml for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, probably you missed the correct place in the documentation about that:

If you open [Import Strategy](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-import-strategy.html) you'll find a section `Per BootstrapView`, you should be using something like `REPLACE_EXISTING` or `UPDATE_EXISTING` for your ACP packaged content (if you're using ACPs as your bootstrap importing strategy).

[Here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/ACP#Import_UUID_Bindings) is a more detailed description of the `UUID Bindings` values.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use patches.
When alfresco server starts it applies patches and executes database updates etc.

Definition :

> A patch is a piece of Java code that executes once when Alfresco
>   Content Services starts. Custom patches can be implemented.

[Documentation Link](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-patch.html)